# Python: No module named contextlib?

Tags: python

Does anyone know where i can find this python module 'contextlib'?

```
root@overo:~# python                                                            
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Mar  9 2011, 10:05:36)                                
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2                                                           
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.          
>>> import contextlib                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                           
ImportError: No module named contextlib
```

I did not compile python myself personally. I'm just in this mess. It's running on an ARM based CPU so maybe some things were left out to save space.

I ran `find / | grep contextlib` which resulted in nothing.

Can i download this module from somewhere and just plonk it in /usr/lib/python2.6? Will that work?

Comment: did you compile cpython manually?

Comment: I did not compile manually. I think someone did a custom job of packaging this all up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have noted, that module *should* be in the standard library, but if it's an embedded device, it may have been dropped to save space (if true, a foolish choice IMO, since leaving out `contextlib.contextmanager` robs the `with` statement of much of its power and convenience)

If you can name the specific device or manufacturer (or ask the vendor directly), you may be able to get a better answer.

As far as fixing it goes, grabbing http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/contextlib.py and dropping it in `sys.path` somewhere should do the trick (running `python -m site` will dump the list of directories that you can use)

Answer (score 12):

I got this error in a different way.

I created a pipenv virtual environment using the 32bit version of Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10. I then realized I needed the 64bit version. Uninstalled the 32bit, installed the 64bit, and then tried to go back to my existing virtual env. The previously created env was now broken in odd ways and gave me this error.

I solved this by removing the old pipenv `pipenv --rm` and creating a new one with the newly installed version of python.

Answer (score 8):

It has been part of the standard library since 2.5 according to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html). It seems a bit weird that you don't have it, it works with 2.6.6 for me (Ubuntu 10.10):

```
blair@blair-eeepc:~$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import contextlib
>>> contextlib.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.6/contextlib.pyc'
```

Somebody may have a better suggestion, but if it comes to it there is a link at the top of the documentation to the source code (which is Python, so you should be able to use it directly without any compilation or anything).

**Edit**: Unless, as Santiago Lezica suggested, you compiled your copy of Python manually, in which case it should be a simple matter of copying the module into the correct library path.

**Edit for updated question**: To the best of my knowledge, just dropping the source into a directory on the Python path should work. You could do this in the system library, but, to avoid it being deleted/replaced/otherwise borked in future updates, I'd recommend putting it in a separate directory and adding that directory to the Python path. You could put it under /usr/local, or somewhere in your home directory.

Comment: I have updated the question. It's all running on an ARM based cpu, so maybe it was left out to save space. I did not compile it myself.

Answer (score 2):

With Angsrom Linux, contextlib is included in the python-misc package. You can grab it by running:

```
opkg install python-misc
```

This won't, however, get you all expected python modules, so you may also want to install python-modules:

```
opkg install python-modules
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one more occasion, which produces the same error.
I had made a virtual environment with python 3.6. After a updated my python version to 3.7 I tried to activate the old virtual environment and got this error.

The solution was to delete the old environment and recreate it with the new python version.

Comment: I also have this problem, and I guess that your answer seems most related to my issue. However, I don't understand _why_ this error occurs. And I don't like to recreate all my virtual environments. Did you ever find out what was causing the problem and if there's another way to fix this then to recreate the virtual environment? Since a virtual environment contains a copy of the Python installation, I don't understand why updating the global (system) Python version would affect the virtual environment...

Answer (score 0):

Check `sys.path` to make sure your python interpreter is looking in the right directories.  It should look something like this (not necessarily identical):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6']
```

EDIT: With the updated information in the question that this is an install of unknown origin on a constrained device, assuming that unnecessary modules were removed to save space makes sense.  However, for the record, I'll mention another, perhaps more common scenario where modules cannot be found: when there are file permissions issues.  For example:

```
$ python -c 'import contextlib; print(contextlib.__file__)'
/usr/lib/python2.6/contextlib.pyc
$ ls -l /usr/lib/python2.6/contextlib.py*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4136 Dec 26 16:42 /usr/lib/python2.6/contextlib.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4127 Jan  1 21:45 /usr/lib/python2.6/contextlib.pyc
$ sudo chmod go-r /usr/lib/python2.6/contextlib.py*
$ python -c 'import contextlib; print(contextlib.__file__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named contextlib
```

Especially with custom installations, import problems due to file permission issues and path problems are some of the easiest things to check and, usually, to fix.

Comment: Hi Ned, i checked /usr/lib/python2.6 and it doesn't have contextlib.py at all. I am thinking it was left out of the distribution.

Comment: A similar issue that looks like Ned's is if you naively call a module "site.py". Because site.py is used in the import machinery, if you make a file with this name - very strange/bad things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2
`sudo apt-get install python-contextlib2`

Python 3
`sudo apt-get install python3-contextlib2`

Answer (score -1):

[contextlib](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html) was introduced in Python 2.5, can you remove and re-install your Python 2.6.6 again?  From my copy of Python 2.6.6:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import contextlib
>>>
```