# ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh triggers error while installing GCloud SDK in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to install GCloud SDK in Ubuntu 18.04.
I have python 3.6 installed in the system.
Error says :

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud CLI!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anm/Durgendra Workspace/WebDev/sdk/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/home/anm/Durgendra Workspace/WebDev/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 32, in <module>
    import setup  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "/home/anm/Durgendra Workspace/WebDev/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 57, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import platforms
  File "/home/anm/Durgendra Workspace/WebDev/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/home/anm/Durgendra Workspace/WebDev/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/home/anm/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/home/anm/lib/python3.6/importlib/util.py", line 13, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contextlib'
```

To solve this I tried to install contextlib using

```
pip install contextlib2
```

But this is of no use.

Comment: Which method did you use to install the CLI? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb

Comment: I guess I used the wrong tab (i.e. Linux). Let me try this with Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried the commands under Debian/Ubuntu tab. But still getting the same error while executing "gcloud init"

Comment: @Durgendra, Have you got any error while executing commands as per document https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb.

Comment: Yes, I am still facing above issue. Not getting any fix over this contextlib.

Comment: @Durgendra have you referred with this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520515/python-no-module-named-contextlib and https://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/