# How to uninstall kivy without pip

Tags: python

I deleted python and reinstalled it to try and fix a problem but am now stuck because I had a virtual environment installed. I believe to fix the problem I must uninstall kivy but am unsure how to do so without pip uninstall as I can't run this as a consequence. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok, what are the logs or output from command you want to use

Comment: @Kozubi for every pip command I run I get this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contextlib'` I can't post the whole thing because its too long

Comment: try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520515/python-no-module-named-contextlib

Comment: @Kozubi it doesn't work unfortunately because all of their solutions use pip

Comment: Do you have python installed and where?
About - python virtual env - if you dont use it just remove folder with them